# Image Carousel component in SnapChat's Lens Studio

Tags: scripting, snapchat

:)

I am not a coder & never did any scripting. I am working on a lens in Lens Studio that displays certain artworks on screen.
I want to add a carousel so the users can go back and forth the index rather than just tapping in forward direction cycle.
I downloaded a component from assets library called Image Carousel by Snap Inc.
It allows me to add the icons for the carousel which I can scroll and tap but there is a script that is required and snapchat itself has not dedicated a page in their website that shows how to use this component.
*(I also posted the similar question in the their community forum no luck so far.)*

When clicked on component in the resources panel a box with this text appears in the inspector panel:
Image Carousel

Provides a carousel UI for the selection of one image between many. Requires a ScreenTransform.
For a vertical orientation (or any other orientation) change the z rotation of your screen transform.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAyju.jpg)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njc00.png)

*=== EVENTS ===

- onSelectionUpdate(i,tex)
  'i' is the index of the item in the carousel
  'tex' is the texture of the icon that was selected

Registering for the event from another script:

```
 script.carouselCC.onSelectionUpdate.add(function(i,tex) {...});
```

## API

- size(): int
  Returns the number of items in the carousel
- setSelected(int index, bool animate): void
  Select item at index, animate to position if animate === true
- getSelected(): int
  Returns the currently selected item index, or -1 if the carousel is empty
- getCentered(): int
  Returns the item index closest to center (also while dragging/animating)
- add(Texture image): int
  Add an item to the end of the carousel with image
  Returns the new image index
- remove(int index): bool
  Remove image at index, returns false if index is out of bounds
- setImage(int index, Texture image): bool
  Set image at index, returns false if index is out of bounds
- getImage(int index): Texture
  Returns the image texture for index, or null if index is out of bounds
- getSelectedImage(): Texture
  Returns the currently selected image texture, or null is the carousel is empty
- setLocked(int index, bool locked): void
  Show/Hide locked badge on the icon
- getLocked(int index): bool
  Get locked state for icon index
- setData(int index, Object data) : void
  Set private data associated with this icon
- getData(int index): Object
  Get private data associated with this icon
- enableInteraction(): void
  Enable UI
- disableInteraction(): void
  Disable UI
- show(): void
  Show carousel (fade-in)
- hide(): void
  Hide carousel (fade-out)
- isVisible(): bool
  Returns visibility

I have no idea which one to use or how.*

All I want is a way to connect the icons srceen images for example Image 1 with Screen Image 1, Image 2 with Screen Image 2, Image 3 with Screen Image 3, so that when I scroll and tap to Image 3 in carousel the Screen Image 3 appears on screen.

The image carousel component has a panel called "On Item Set Call" where you put the script but using Behavior script and then the function name.
[This area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq3uq.png)

Since I don't know what or how hard this is I might be asking alot for being a noob in this so I apologize in advance on the same hand I will be very very thankful in anyone spares some time helping me out with this.

Cheers!!!!

The Command are from SnapChat Lens Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this component for what you want to achieve.
The Carousel allows you to take the index of the main item, and pass it to a separate script that you create.

You need to drag an active script component (from the objects panel) into the field 'Script' under the menu title 'On Item Set Call' and then expose a function from your script that is passed the index of the current carousel item (the one facing the front).

In my example, I've created a script called 'UI Script' with this public function:

```
// -----JS CODE-----
//@input Component.Image[] items;

script.setItem = function(index){
    for(var i = 0;i < script.items.length; i++){
        if(i == index){
            script.items[i].enabled = true;
        }
        else{
            script.items[i].enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

It enables a given image from an array of images corresponding with the index.
Of course you can do different things with the script, for example taking an array of texture assets as an input and setting the texture of an image component based on the index.

Hope this helps!

[the script component and function referenced in the carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn0BK.png)

Comment: OK so I created a script in the resources panel and added the code you shared, then I created a behavior scrip in objects panel and dragged and dropped the new script in the behavior then dragged the behavior script to image carousel's inspector panel and dropped in the On Item Set Call panel in Script. 

Nothing happened
But in the mid of writing this comment I realized it needs "Function Name" and I saw in the script you share its called "setItem" and it worked :

TBH I wasn't expecting any help 
CHEERS ) ❤️‍

Comment: I'm glad that helped! Have passed on the request for some documentation for this component. Happy developing!

Comment: For future reference:
this component now has a section in the documentation https://docs.snap.com/lens-studio/references/guides/lens-features/ui-outline/ui-image-carousel